# Laravel relations with multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am building a blog application and I have

`Post`, `City`, `Neighbourhood`, `SubNeighbourhood`.

The relations that I have until now are between `City`, `Neighbourhood` and `subNeighbourhood` like follows:

```
subNeighbourhood belongs to Neighbourhood 
Neighbourhood belongs to city
```

The second relation is like

```
City hasMany Neighbourhoods 
Neighbourhood hasMany subNeighbourhoods
```

My problems are when I create the post. The posts table have `id_city`, `id_neighbourhood` and `id_subNeighbourhood`.

The questions that I have are:

If the post structure is correct? I feel like having many "id_..." is not ok.

Second issue is how do I write the relation in posts? All the columns "id_..." are having foreign keys to each corresponding table.

Comment: Normal convention in eloquent is `*_id` notation instead of `id_*`

Comment: can you give me a example link to this? thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships. You can also alter the column name for relations if you want to and you are free to do so.  What kind of relations do you want from you Post model to the other models?

Comment: Polymorphic relations can be really interesting for your use case. You get a `relation_id` field and a `relation_type` field. 

As example a post on a city will get the id of the city in `relation_id` and as `relation_type` something like `App\Models\City::class`

Comment: I want to be able to say $post->city or $post->neighbourhood or $post->subNeighbourhood. I am not sure how to do this in a proper way. I can also do something like $post->subneighbourhood->neighbourhood>city but I don't know if this is the proper way.

Comment: Answer is on the way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can understand from your explanation the post table should have only a subneighbourhood_id field, in the Post class the relation should be:

```
public function subneighbourhood()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subneighbourhood');
```

So a Post belongs to a Subneighbourhood that belongs to a Neighbourhood that belongs to a City

Comment: I understand you logic but if I want to do get the city for a post I should write $post->subneighbourhood->neighbourhood>city, correct? and on the save of the post how do I write the hole relation until the city? I am new to this complex things so it is not clear for me. thanks

Comment: From the logic you wrote the relation is clear and is this one you wrote: $post->subneighbourhood->neighbourhood>city. If you wrote another city_id field in the post table you could have $post->city but the two cities could be different, I cant imagine a scenario for this.

Comment: can you give me more details regarding this scenario? this part i don't get it, why there is this possibility for the two cities to be different?

Comment: if you have a post table with subneighbourhood_id and city_id fields you have a Post model with two belongsTo relations, one with  subneighbourhood and another with city, but you subneighbourhood belongs_to to neighbourhood that belongs to City so your Post model has two City, one in direct relation and the other through sub-neighbourhood.

Comment: ok, i got it, but then why do you say that this are different cities? after all the city id will be the same right?

Comment: I wrote that they **could** be different, probably depending on user input, and you have to write specific code in a lot of places to assure they remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think a polymorphic relation will be a nice solution to your problem. (I didn't test my code or what so ever)

```
class Post extends Model
{
   // Can return a City or Neighbourhood or SubNeighbourhood
   public function related() {
      return $this->morphTo();
   }
}

class City extends Model 
{
   public function posts() {
      return $this->morphMany(App\Models\Post::class, 'related');
   }
} 


class Neighbourhood extends Model 
{
   public function posts() {
      return $this->morphMany(App\Models\Post::class, 'related');
   }
}
```

How to use this:

Example if we have a post that's related to a city

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$true = ($post->related instanceof City);  // This will be true if post related to a city
$neightbourhoods = $post->related->neightbourhoods(); // All the neightbourhoods of the city
```

Example if we have a post that's related to a neighbourhood

```
$post = Post::find(2);
$true = ($post->related instanceof Neighbourhood); // This will be true if post is related to a neighbourhood
//In this case we can do
$post->neighbourhood->subNeighbourhoods(); // All the sub neighbourhoods
```

You can safe post easily with

```
$post = new Post();
$post->related = City::find(1); 
$post->save();

or 

$post = new Post();
$post->related = Neighbourhood::find(1);
$post->save();
```

Comment: I've created your solution in my code, but when I will in all the details of the post (title, content and so on) I can't save. The morph is not doing the same like belongsTo, right? (i mean to automatically add the city id to city_id)

Comment: the morph is a bit smarter and takes into account which model is attached to it.  It sets the id of the model always on `related_id` and it determines which table to query for the relation on the `related_type` field. So if `related_type` is "city" the cities table will be queried. If the type is "neighbourhood" the neighbourhoods table is queried.